# Asp.Net Core WebApi collection parameter

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi, endpoint

I have the following WebAPI method:

```
    [Route("Api/FuelTransaction/Efs")]
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual IActionResult Efs(IEnumerable<TransactionDto> fuelTransactions)
    {
```

where TransactionDto is:

```
public class TransactionDto
{
    //N/A to the customer.
    public int ARBatchNumber { get; set; }
```

I try to call this method from Postman:

[image]

But I receive empty collection. What is wrong?

Comment: ok well in that case try using `[FromBody]` and see if that makes a difference. Cause everything else looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add `[FromBody]` attribute for parameter (thank you Nkosi for help):

```
public virtual IActionResult Efs([FromBody]IEnumerable<TransactionDto> fuelTransactions)
{
```

Comment: Yeah with dot net core you have to be more specific about where the data is binding from.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2